# What HTML5 Tag Should be Used for a "Call to Action" Div?

Tags: seo, html

I am new to HTML5 and am wondering which HTML5 tag should be used on a Call to Action div that sits in a column next to the main content on the home page.

Option 1:

```
<aside>
    //call to action
</aside>
```

Option 2:

```
<article>
    <section>
       //call to action
    </section>
</article>
```

The reason I ask is because I don't see either option as being a perfect fit.  Perhaps I am missing something.  Thanks!

My HTML for the Call to Action:

```
        <section class="box">
            <hgroup>
                <h1 class="side">Call Now</h1>
                <h2 class="side">To Schedule a Free Pick-Up!</h2>
                    <ul class="center">
                        <li>Cleaning</li>
                        <li>Repair</li>
                        <li>Appraisals</li>
                    </ul>
                <h3 class="side no-bottom">(781) 729-2213</h3>
                <h4 class="side no-top no-bottom">Ask for Bob!</h4>
            </hgroup>
            <img class="responsive" src="img/satisfaction-guarantee.png" alt="100% Satisfaction Guarantee">
            <p class="side">We guarantee you will be thrilled with our services or your money back!</p>
        </section>
```

This is a box on the right column of a three column layout.  The content in the large middle column gives a summary of the company's services.  If you wanted to use those services, you would have to schedule a pick-up, hence the call to action.

Does anyone object to this use of HTML5, or have a better way?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a div?

Comment: I was under the impression that HTML5 was meant to give more meaning to content.  Of course I could just use a div but my question is what is the most relevant option?

Comment: HTML5 is intended to be more semantic. Which tag would give more context to the "call to action" content, an article or an aside? If neither is appropiate, then like @Brendon said, use a DIV.

Comment: I'll go for `<a>` too. If content is text why not `<h3><a>call to action</a></h3>`. And for a button use `<button>`.

Comment: You know: I've *never* been 'thrilled' with cleaning, repair or appraisals. *Satisfied*, yes; but never *thrilled*. Where do you, or the relevant company, operate? I think I'd like to call...

Comment: 1) Why on earth do you use headings for your *content* (`h3`, `h4`)? 2) `hgroup` is not allowed to contain `ul`. 3) the answer to your question depends on the *whole* page content/context (→ is the call to action part of the main content of the page or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper markup depends on the actual content, which you have not provided.

That said, wrapping everything in a div is fine (although perhaps unnecessary) no matter what your content is as the `<div>` tag has no semantic value. Your two examples are probably not correct, unless your "call to action" is literally an entire article (which I doubt is the case).

The call to action might occur within an `<aside>`, but it's not likely that the call to action *is* the aside itself. Once again, that depends on the *content* (what it is) and *context* (where it is in relation to other content).

Typically "call to action" is a link somewhere, so the obvious answer to me is using an anchor, `<a>`.

Comment: I've added some context to my question.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's difficult to say with much confidence, it might be an `aside` or it might belong to the main content of a page. I don't suspect it would be a `section`, per the spec: "*A general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's outline.*".. but then again, that may be the case. I would say this one's really up to you, probably either `aside` or `section` if anything, definitely not an `article` by itself, but it might make sense within one. It's your call, and it looks like you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 7):

My take is that the best practices for the new HTML5 structural elements are still being worked out, and the forgiving nature of the new HTML5 economy means that you can establish the conventions that make the most sense for your application.

In my applications, I have separate considerations for markup that reflects *the layout of the view* (that is, the template that creates the overall consistency from page to page) versus *the content itself* (usually any function or query results that receive additional markup before being inserted into the various regions in the layout). The distinction matters because the layout element semantics (like header, footer, and aside) don't really help with differentiation of the content during search since that markup is usually repeated from page to page. I particularly favor using the semantic distinctions in HTML5 to describe the content the user is actually searching on. For example I generally use article to wrap the primary content and nav to wrap any associated list of links. Widget wrappers are usually tied to the page layout, so I'd go with the convention of the template for that guideline.

Whenever I have to decide on semantic vs generic names, my general heuristic is:

- If there is a possible precedent already in the page template, follow that precedent;
- If the element in question is new part of the page layout (vs a content query that is rendered into a region in the layout) and there is no guiding pattern in the template already, div is fine for associating that page layout behavior to;
- If the content is created dynamically (that is, anything that gets instanced into the layout at request time--posts, navigation, most widgets), wrap it in a semantic wrapper that best describes what that item is (vs how you think it should appear)
- Whenever authoring or generating content, use semantic HTML5 markup as appropriate within that content (hgroup to bracket hierarchical headings, section to organize chunks within the article, etc.). This is future-proof enrichment for search.

According to all this, div would be fine as a wrapper for your widget unless your page template already establishes a different widget wrapper. Also, your use of heading elements for creating large, bold appearance within the widget is using markup for appearance rather than for semantics. Since your particular usage is appearance-motivated, it would be better to use divs or spans with CSS classes that can let you specify sizes, spacing, and other adornments as needed for that non-specific text rather than having to override the browser defaults for the heading elements. I'd save the heading elements for the page heading, for widget headings, and for headings within the primary content region of the page. There can be SEO ranking issues for misuse of headings that are not part of the main content.

I hope these ideas help in your consideration of HTML5 markup usage.

Answer (score 3):

So far as the semantics of the markup go, Don's advice makes sense. (As you said your CTA was visually beside the main content and secondary to that content, I would favor `aside`, but there's no single correct answer.)

However, you've tagged your question with "seo," so I take it you're interested in the SEO benefits of using the right markup. At this time, Google doesn't give special weight to having nice, semantic markup---they don't care about the difference between things like `aside`, `section`, and `div`. This may be partly because the meaning of these tags is still being defined (by the practice of Web devs), but they even seem to ignore tags that are clearly relevant search results (like `nav`, which will almost always be irrelevant to a page's description in the search results).

Instead, they heavily favor [using microdata](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176035) for marking up rich semantics. In the short term, marking your page up using the Schema.org [WebPage](http://schema.org/WebPage) microdata will likely provide greater benefit. You can mark your CTA as a `relatedLink` or `significantLink`, and keep it outside the `mainContent` of the page. If you're looking to optimize your page for search, this is a great way to do it---in my experience, Google very rarely shows text outside of your `mainContent` block in the search results description.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a link to another page. Use a div.